# Measure theory and Lebesgue integration

Tags: measure-theory

I am having a problem anwsering the question that my professor posted on his website (it should prepare students for an upcoming exam). I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Let $f$ be a measurable fuction on $[1,\infty)$, bounded on bounded sets.

Let $a_{n}=\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)d \lambda_{1}(x)$, $\ \ n=1,2,\dots$

$i)$ Is it true that $f$ is an integrable function on $[1,\infty)$ iff series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent.

$ii)$ Is it true that $f$ is an integrable function on $[1,∞)$ iff series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is absolutely convergent.

Justify your anwser.

Answer (score 0):

For i) consider the function $f=\sum_n (-1)^n {1 \over n}1_{[n,n+1]}$. $f$ is not integrable, but the $a_n$ are summable.

For ii) consider the function $f=1_{A_+} -1_{A_-}$, where $A_+ = [0,{1\over 2})+ \mathbb{Z}$, $A_+ = [{1\over 2},1]+ \mathbb{Z}$. Then $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, which is summable, but $f$ is not integrable.

(Actually, the answer to ii) would suffice as an answer for  both!)

Comment: It is interesting to note that if $f\geqslant 0$, the first claim is true.

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't $a_n = (-1)^n$ in your first example?  The series $\sum_n (-1)^n$ doesn't converge...

Comment: @SpamIAm: Thanks for catching that, I added in the missing ${1 \over n}$!